# Unit testing examples that proves that unit tests are worth writing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have read a lot about unit testing, but I still haven't found any good examples that would show why unit testing is worth the time.

I would like to see actual Java code that shows how unit test is done and how it will catch possible bugs.

Comment: What is your criteria for "proof" that unit testing is "worth" doing? Unit testing provides automated regression testing, which makes your code easier to change (and to know that your changes didn't break previously working code). The "proof" comes when a unit test catches a regression that you otherwise wouldn't have found until after deploying into production which can be embarrassing, cause real damage to the user, etc. Example code of a single unit test does not provide any specific "proof."

Comment: People are stupid, so they make mistakes (I am no exception). Unit tests help you track down those stupid mistakes.

Comment: Are you questioning the rationale behind unit testing or automated tests altogether?

Comment: @ponzao I'm just asking for examples that could help me to understand unit testing.

Comment: @Mark S I'd just want to see some examples HOW unit tests are done in practise, and if example was intelligent it would of course be more motivating to write tests, if example test was good..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unit testing is not about catching possible bugs, its about 'feeling a little bit safe'. Good example is a project with code base larger than hello world with multiple developers. It is only a matter of time, when somebody breaks something, what was working before. The question is - when will you know it? After the application is deployed or during development?

Comment: +1: Regression testing (checking existing functionality to ensure it hasn't been broken by later modifications to the code) is one of the biggest benefits to Unit Testing to my mind - especially when you're working on a large project where developers don't know the ins and outs of every piece of code and hence are likely to introduce bugs by incorrectly working with code written by other developers.

Comment: I think it's more than confidence, but I agree with your point. I'd want to stress that the tests need to represent correct functionality, and not self-serving implementation details. Unit testing doesn't guarantee zero defects or make the quality of the code inherently better. The benefit is realized when thought is invested during development -- we think through what the code needs to do, its lifetime and usage -- construction faults are realized sooner, and the design influenced for extensibility. It's a mindset and craft, you get better as you practice.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the benefits that are described by other commenters, I think that unit testing, and automated unit testing, have a positive effective on the design of your production code. Designing code that is testable tends to lead you to a much more loosely coupled design, the benefits of which are widely documented.

Comment: +1 I definitely agree with this answer. Thinking about how you are going to test your code as you write it tends to lead to a better separation of concerns throughout your code, with dependencies between components and classes reduced to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of when I wish I had had unit tests.

We used the decorator pattern to convert an IBitmapStream from one format into another using a number of BitmapConverter classes. A BitmapConvertor class is itself an IBitmapStream:
[image: BitmapConverters]

We had a number of bitmap converters, to convert bit depth, color spaces transformations(grey, RGB, CMYK), row padding, color component ordering, special effects, ...

We had no automated testing. So when we fixed bugs in any single converter, it required a lot of manual discipline and effort to test the converters through our GUI with a number of different test bitmaps.

The bugs were often subtle - they first became apparent when we tested a number of converters chained together - and a disadvantage of the decorator pattern is the difficulty in debugging.
And fixing one bug often led to breaking another case.

It would have saved an enormous amount of time and stress if we had had an automated set of tests.

For each bug found by our QM department (or customer) we in development would have first written a unit test to replicate the bug, and then fix the code, and make sure the fix has not broken any other tests.

Answer (score 0):

I can't just give an example without some elucidation. Writing unit tests is time consuming. Therefore, it is difficult to convince managers and colleagues about their being worthwhile. I write unit tests during the coding phase of development, and it can extend coding duration by 50 - 100%.

Is it worth it? I think so. Unit tests locate bugs before integration with other code modules. Also, if they check most of the run scenarios properly, they are very effective in locating broken code after development is over (maintenance).

Here's a simple example how to use JUnit 4.x:

```
public class UnitTests {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        A a = new A();
        String s = " Hello ";
        String result = a.trim(s);

        assertEquals("The String wasn't trimmed", "Hello", result);
    }
}

public class A {
    public String trim(String s) {
        return s.trim();
    }
}
```

Since String.trim() removes both leading and trailing whitespace, and since the string s contains both leading and trailing whitespace, if someone later changes the method A.trim() to do something else, for example to trim only leading or trailing whitespace, this test will fail.